# Can I combine two partition without reinstall OS?

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, partitioning

I got a 320GB harddisk, which was partitioned into C: and D:, the C: was used to be the OS, and D: contains other stuff.

But now I bought another harddisk which is 1TB, now I want to combine C: and D: so that I only have 2 drives for simplicity reason.

Can it be done without damaging the files in drive C: and D:?

The os is Win XP.

Comment: Based on your description, I'm assuming you're using Windows.  What version, exactly?

Comment: oh oh, it is a xp.

Comment: You should be able to do this. I would get a third-party partition program, it should allow you to delete the D and merge it in the C directory.  I strongly advise you to get away from Windows XP it is not a secure operating system.

Comment: Please recommend a software, if someone have done this before successfully.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend [Gparted Live CD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) to repartition your drive. You *must* backup your files, ideally create a full disk image that you can use to do a full restore, in case something goes wrong.

Windows XP (and other versions) are quite unforgiving when you change partition sizes, sometimes it fails to boot. So you do this at your own risk, and be sure to **Back Up**.

**Update:** To make full disk backups before try [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/).

Comment: I've used gparted to resize NTFS partitions many times without ever causing a problem ... that wasn't my fault. Work carefully and it should be fine. But BACK UP ANYWAY.

Comment: Indeed, windows doesn't know or care if it has been resized; millions of people do that all the time.

Comment: Easus is also a good option, but yes, always back up before modifying your partitions.

Comment: I have seen resizing a partition make XP ask for reactivation once.  Just once though.